# How to set the connection string on another computer for access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, database-connection, ms-access-2007, connection-string

I created very simple winform with access database, i have 3 pcs i choose one of them to host the database (shared), and i created a .udl (data link properties) on the other two computers and i configured the path for the shared database, the test connection was successful, i opened the udl file and i have the connection string `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\PCName\c$\temp\Database1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False` My question, where will i put the connection string? do i need to have the program solution just to put it?

Answer (score 1):

You can define the connection string in [app.config](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: if i create a setup will the app.config be included?